# Public.class lab1 or public class lab1?

Tags: java, class

Is there a difference between "public.class lab1" and "public class lab1"? Should periods be avoided in place of spaces since certain commands use them?

Comment: Did you try the first syntax?

Comment: Yes there is a difference, first one doesn't compile.

Comment: Can you share some examples and make your question more clear

Answer (score 1):

There is most certainly a difference, by putting a period in the middle you are not following the syntax of java. This will cause an error. The correct way of putting that there would be by putting a space where the period was. This will not lead to an error. Hope that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is definitely a difference as the first will not compile properly.

This is because every programming language, including Java, has a certain syntax that the compiler can read and interpret. With a dot in between public and class, the class definition is not valid anymore and this is considered a syntax error.

Comment: This should be considered as positive answer since he directly answered to the original question.